# Live preview and Inspect in VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Well, Live Preview extension allows to preview an HTML file inside the VS code, unfortunately an inspection of the code can't be done the same way, e.g. by use of browser.

[image]

Although in VS code is still an integrated option to see the output, there is no advanced report like if you'd use Inspect. This is the only extension I found and is useless in this case?

Comment: Did you find anything that could inspect html elements in vscode?